# How to find a predecessor of a minimum element in a linked list implementation of a queue?

Tags: c++

so i want to find a predecessor of a minimum element in a queue. I have used a linked list implementation of a queue. I have been able to find a minimum element in a queue, but i have no idea how to find a predecessor of a minimum element. For example lets say a queue consits of elements like: [5 3 1 4]. I need to find the element 3, as it is the predecessor of the minimum element which in this case is 1. Thanks in advance for any help.

Here's what I have done so far:

```
template <typename InfoType>
void LQueue <InfoType>::MinElementP() {
    Node *min = head;
    Node *h = head;
        
    while (h != 0){
        if (min->info > h->info){
            min->info = h->info;
        }
        h = h->next;
    }
    
    cout << "Minimum element (the smallest element) in this queue is : " << min->info << "\n";
}
```

Comment: What would the predecessor be for a list `[1 2 3 4]`?  Elements of a queue aren't guaranteed to have a "predecessor".

Comment: Then I guess i wouldn't be able to find a predecessor, as the minimum element is in the beggining of the queue

Comment: _"Then I guess i wouldn't be able to find a predecessor"_ What is the expected behavior in this case? You could simply use an additional pointer pointing to the predecessor.

Comment: just remember the last `Node` you passed, eg `auto previous = h` before `h = h->next`

Comment: Sorry, but i don't get your question, do you mean what do I need put in the code or?

Comment: the question is what do you want your code to do when the list is 1 2 3 4. As it isnt possible to return the predecessor of the minimum, the code has to do something else. What do you want it to do in that case?

Comment: Thank you, I got it working now, with the pointer that points to the predecessor.

Comment: @ahmedskulj10 _"I got it working now"_ Are you saying that you no longer are asking this question?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 i need to put the if statement, so when the minimum is in the beggining, i can output on the screen the message that the predecessor can't be find or something like that

Comment: Better would be to have a function that returns the pointer, and if it needs to handle the case of no result for inapplicable input then return an `std::optional<>` pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working now, i initialized a new pointer that points to the predecessor, just before the `h= h->next;` statement, so for example `predecessor = h;`

Answer (score -1):

What type of variables have you created in `node`? If it has a `key` in ascending order to keep track of your nodes, then you can get the key of predecessor by subtracting one from `key of node with minimum value`.
Or you could create a double linked link list which points to previous element as well by making a pointer named `previous` in `node` type.